# Integer number too large in Long type variable

Tags: java, integer

I tried to declare fixed array objects for testing, to remove the need to reenter objects on every run.

The array test objects are like this:

```
studentList[0].setStudent("Mr", "Jason", "Lee", 00001, 01, 01,2001, 85, 75, 8, 65, 72.5, "D");
studentList[1].setStudent("Miss", "Candice", "Teo", 00002, 02, 02, 2002, 95, 95, 9, 90, 92.0, "HD");
studentList[2].setStudent("Mrs", "Sophie", "Chua", 00003, 03, 03, 2003, 65, 78, 7, 92, 81.6, "HD");
studentList[3].setStudent("Mrs", "Brendon", "Low", 00004, 04, 04, 2004, 95, 98, 7, 69, 80.1, "HD");
studentList[4].setStudent("Mr", "Clarance", "Yeo", 00005, 05, 05, 2005, 80, 76, 5, 59, 65.7, "C");
studentList[5].setStudent("Mr", "Adrian", "Tan", 00006, 06, 06, 2006, 70, 60, 4, 20, 40.0, "ND");
studentList[6].setStudent("Ms", "Debbie", "Toh", 00007, 07, 07, 2007, 60, 60, 7, 50, 56.0, "P");
studentList[7].setStudent("Miss", "Sarah", "Ho", 00008, 08, 08, 2008, 59, 61, 7, 62, 62.0, "N");
studentList[8].setStudent("Mr", "Aloysius", "Lim", 00009, 09, 09, 2009, 62, 63, 8, 69, 67.5, "C");
studentList[9].setStudent("Mrs", "Peggy", "Lo", 00010, 10, 10, 2010, 65, 67, 9, 72, 71.4, "D");
```

They are an array object containing

`studentTitle` (String),

`studentFirstName` (String),

`studentLastName` (String),

`studentID` (Long),

and the rest are scores of (Int) and lastly `grade`of (String).

---

However, an error was shown stating:

`integer number too large: 00008`

`integer number too large: 08`

`integer number too large: 08`

for both on `studentList[7]` and `studentList[8]`.

---

May I know what should be corrected? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`08` and `00008` are parsed as octal numbers, in which 8 and 9 are invalid digits. Remove the leading zeroes.

Comment: will there be an error if the input was stored by user input while the program runs instead of prefixed?

Comment: @gymcode What do you mean? If the input integers are not prefixed by leading zeroes, there won't be any problem.